# Wacom consumer tablet driver service may crash while opening Bamboo Preferences, often after resuming computer from sleep

Tags: windows-7, drivers, crash, graphics-tablet

One of the ExpressKeys on my Wacom Bamboo Capture graphics tablet is mapped to Bamboo Preferences, so that I can quickly access the tablet settings and view the battery level (I have the Wireless Accessory Kit installed).

However, when I connect the tablet to the computer, in wired or wireless mode, and attempt to open Bamboo Preferences, the Wacom consumer tablet driver service may crash, most often when I try to do so after resuming the computer from sleep.  There is usually no direct indication of the crash (although I once did get *Tablet Service for consumer driver stopped working and was closed*), only that the cursor shows that the system is busy for a split second.  When this happens, the pen no longer tracks on the screen when in proximity of the tablet (even though it is detected by the tablet itself); however, touch continues to function correctly.

To recover from this condition, I need to restart the tablet driver services.  I got tired of having to go through Task Manager to restart the service every time this happens, so I ended up writing the following command script, with a shortcut on the desktop for running it with elevated privileges:

```
net stop TabletServicePen
net start TabletServicePen
net stop TouchServicePen
net start TouchServicePen
```

Is there something I can do to prevent these crashes from happening in the first place, or do I have have to deal with this issue until the driver is updated?

Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.  Tablet drivers are up to date.

### Technical details

Action Center gives the following details about the crash in Reliability Monitor:

> #### Source
>
> Tablet Service for consumer driver
>
> #### Summary
>
> Stopped working
>
> #### Date
>
> ‎10/‎15/‎2012 2:48 PM
>
> #### Status
>
> Report sent
>
> #### Description
>
> Faulting Application Path:    C:\Program Files\Tablet\Pen\Pen_Tablet.exe
>
> #### Problem signature
>
> Problem Event Name:   `APPCRASH` 
> Application Name: `Pen_Tablet.exe` 
> Application Version:  `5.2.5.5` 
> Application Timestamp:    `4e694ecd` 
> Fault Module Name:    `Pen_Tablet.exe` 
> Fault Module Version: `5.2.5.5` 
> Fault Module Timestamp:   `4e694ecd` 
> Exception Code:   `c0000005` 
> Exception Offset: `00000000002f6cde` 
> OS Version:   `6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3` 
> Locale ID:    `1033` 
> Additional Information 1: `9d4f` 
> Additional Information 2: `9d4f1c8d2c16a5d47e28521ff719cfba` 
> Additional Information 3: `375e` 
> Additional Information 4: `375ebb9963823eb7e450696f2abb66cc`
>
> #### Extra information about the problem
>
> Bucket ID:    `45598085`

Exception code `0xC0000005` means [`STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).  The event log contains essentially the same information.

Comment: I can verify that I have the same problem with a Cintiq.

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't the Cintiq use `WTabletServicePro`, not `WTabletServiceCon`? I'd assume the professional tablet driver should be more stable than the consumer tablet driver...